# Is this JS Object allowed?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a complier error with the following JS object.

Is this allowed/if so wheres my syntax wrong?

```
var optionData = { 
    { option:'', country:{} },
    { option:'', country:{} }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `optionData = []` - it needs to be an array

Comment: Not allowed. It will give syntax error. Either add property to object or create array of objects.

Comment: Object is a collection of `key->value`. To have collection with numeric indexes, use `array`. Try this: `var optionData = [{
  option: '',
  country: {}
}, {
  option: '',
  country: {}
}];`

Answer (score 10):

It should be an array:

```
var optionData = [
    { option: '', country: {} },
    { option: '', country: {} }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be object of array:

```
 var optionData = [
    { option: '', country: {} },
    { option: '', country: {} }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are `key value` pairs.

```
// sample syntax of an object

    var box = {
     "height": 20, // value can be a primitive or reference type
     "width": 40
    };
```